# \textsuperscript inside \section (XeLaTeX)

Tags: xetex, hyperref

How can I get work \textsuperscript inside \section?

```
\documentclass[unicode, fontsize=9pt, twoside=false, russian, a5paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{PT Serif}
\setsansfont{PT Sans Caption}
\setmonofont{PT Mono}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Mapping=tex-text}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=18,pagesize=auto}
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=DarkGreen,
    urlcolor=SteelBlue,
    xetex,
    unicode=true,
    bookmarks=false,
    pdfstartview=FitH,
    pdfpagelayout=OneColumn,
    final=true,
    draft=false,
    debug=false,
]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle{}
\tableofcontents{}

\section{Bla-bla\hyperlink{c_48}{\textsuperscript{\{48\}}}}

\end{document}
```

error:

$ xelatex test.tex:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\hyper@@link ->\let \Hy@reserved@a 
                                   \relax \@ifnextchar [{\hyper@link@ }{\hyp...
l.33 ...hyperlink{c_48}{\textsuperscript{\{48\}}}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\hyperlink` is defined in package `hyperref`.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

And `\protect` before `\hyperlink` lets it survive in the moving argument of `\section`:

```
\section{Bla-bla\protect\hyperlink{c_48}{\textsuperscript{\{48\}}}}
```

Comment: added \usepackage{hyperref}